# Unable to remove border CSS for FullCalendar

Tags: css, fullcalendar

Trying to override the styles of FullCalendar, but running into some issues.

[image]

Within `.fc td, .fc th` on Chrome, I disabled the `border-style` attribute, and thus, there are no border attributes for the `fc-widget-header`. However, I attempted to do this in my CSS using:

```
.fc td, .fc th {
  border-style: none;
}
```

It did not remove the border.

Next, I am trying to remove the `today` border:

[image]

In Chrome, it meant disabling:

```
.fc td.fc-today {
    /* border-style: double; */
}
```

I did that in my CSS, and that also did not work.

Wondering what the issue is?

EDIT:

Ok, so I setup a Fiddle to show you guys it didn't work. However, strangely, it worked in my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/46tnzj72/10/ But not in my actual app.

Comment: Have you tried border: none; ?

Comment: click on "computed" to see how your object is being rendered.

Comment: @ShaharGalukman yes I have.

Comment: @JRQ Im not entirely sure how this helps.

Comment: If you click on "computed" and look at the little picture showing the margin, border, padding, etc.  you should be able to see the border defined, and then click on the definition below to see where the CSS is being declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable reason for this issue was due to the CSS priority levels. If any selector having the higher priority then it overwrites your styles, so for this case you need to write the selector with higher priority level.

Otherwise you can simply use the **`!important`** with you CSS styles, so it doesn't consider any priority and the important style only applied.

```
.fc td, .fc th {
  border-style: none !important;
}
```

(or)

```
.fc td, .fc th {
  border-style: double !important;
  border-width: 3px !important;
  border-color: #aaa !important;
}
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/46tnzj72/11/)

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much. "If any selector having the higher priority then it overwrites your styles, so for this case you need to write the selector with higher priority level." So `!important` basically just means I force that to highest priority?

Comment: yes correct... even `!important` overwrites the inline styles also... so for all the cases it takes the first priority...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by heading but you can remove the border of `Today` by placing the following code in your CSS

```
.fc-right > button{
    border: none;
}
```

**Update**

I just noticed that your border is removed by setting the border of `.fc td, .fc th` to non but your chrome is loading the cached stylesheet so you have to "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)", to do so inspect your element and click the settings symbol then check the check box beside *Disable cache (while DevTools is open)*.
i hope it will help you

Comment: In response to your update, could you clarify? On Chrome, if I set the `border` to `none` on `.fc td, .fc th` (or disable `border-style`) it works. However, if I import that to my code, it does not work. Does it matter that my FullCalendar loads after an AJAX request (I get the JSON data after an AJAX request) and thus the CSS isn't applied?

Comment: it does not matter if your calendar loads later, the CSS will still be applied even if it loads later.

Comment: That's what I thought. It's just so weird to me, since one of the CSS overrides work. But two of them (illustrated in the Fiddle) works in the Fiddle, but not on when imported into my override CSS.

Comment: is your chrome cache disable?

Comment: yes. I ticked the box. I also tried it in incognito mode

Answer (score 0):

use these scss styles

```css
.calendar-wrapper {  
  .fc-scrollgrid {
        border-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .fc-scrollgrid td:last-of-type {
        border-right-color: transparent !important;
    }
    .fc-scrollgrid-section.fc-scrollgrid-section-body td[role='presentation'] {
        border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    }
    [role='row']:last-of-type td {
        border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
    }
    th[role='presentation'] {
        border-right-color: transparent !important;
    }
}
```